# DD-WRT Router Can't hold a connection after initial setup

Tags: networking, router

Struggeling with my new DDWRT router (Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH) configuration. I configured it using one machine while comparing the settings on my existing Linksys WRT54GL on another machine. To the best of my knowledge, I've set it up the same way as my Linksys, but DDWRT has so many other options.

After configuring it, I plugged it into the modem, VOIP device & my network. I see the phones come back online. However after a few minutes, it seems I lose the outbound connection (phones die and I can't get out over HTTP).

What's confusing me is it works for a few minutes, then it fails. No idea what to look for. Ideas?

Comment: What DD-WRT version did you install?  For example *v24 build 14289 vpn*.

Answer (score 0):

Check dd-wrt forums section for your chipset-- at least for Broadcomm (i.e. Linksys), certain versions play nicer with certain hardware. Also saw this after a quick Google http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=437506